# Which one is best practise: A root account for all login user in the system, or multiple user account

Tags: mysql, sql, root, account

Question is, 
I am admin of course I am granted for root access. However, without considering the priviledges given to user, all successful login user should use the same sql database account or multiple users for multiple sql user account is the best practise?

Thanks for enlightening!

Comment: Every user should have their own account

Answer (score 3):

Every user should have his account and every application using db should use different credentials.

Comment: So do you mean that everytime a new user is registered in a system, let say a .NET system,  it should also programmatically register the user in db via CREATE USER account using SQL query?

Comment: @Carn: no, I mean that if you create a db to be accessed from an app you wrote, you should consider creating a superuser account used for superuser of that app and a restricted access account for normal users of that app...

Comment: I see, so you mean that a db account should have different user level for different privilege, but a same privilege user would only need 1 DB User account. Do you think if 100 normal user connect at one time, it would cause any problem as 100 users are using the same DB Account to access

Comment: @Carn: performances are the same... but logging is harder if everyone uses the same account. Think about finding an abuse of someone...
DB server must be "dimensioned" to receive many connections...

Comment: In my case I am working on transaction, and user might place order at any time before market close. I do experience during testing that, the system would wait the other user access to close the connection, and take turn on another.

Comment: @Carn: Are you using a web app or a windows app? I'm not sure if this could be different or not...

Answer (score 0):

Every developer and every role inside an application should have their own account with their own password.

It is immensely useful to log SHOW PROCESSLIST and SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS output for example once every minute and keep it for a week. Together with usernames it becomes much easier to resolve pileups and problems by looking at the usernames in this output.